# Creating a Filtered Data Extension based upon a list

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, dataextensions, sql

I'm trying to filter a data extension where the information pulled in is equal to about any of about 1,000 customer IDs. Is there a way to mass filter a data extension based upon a single customer attribute? Could I write a query something to the effect of "Select * where CustomerID = 12345, or 123456, or 1234567?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would recommend is putting this list of IDs into another DE.

You then can create a query like so:

```
Select a.key, a.field1, a.field2
FROM [yourSourceDe] a
INNER JOIN [yourListDE] b
ON a.key = b.key
WHERE b.key IS NOT NULL
```

Basically what this will do is only grab the records that the 'key' exists in both places.

You can also adjust this to exclude all those in there with a slight modification:

```
Select a.key, a.field1, a.field2
FROM [yourSourceDe] a
LEFT JOIN [yourListDE] b
ON a.key = b.key
WHERE b.key IS NULL
```

This will then only return the records that do not exist in your list DE - meaning all matching records are removed.

If the list is short, you can also do an 'IN':

```
Select key, field1, field2
FROM [yourSourceDe] 
WHERE key IN ('12345',6789',0123')
```

Your target DE in the query will now contained the correctly segmented records.